# Laravel Sanctum and Vue - Unauthenticated

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I have now followed two separate methods for using Laravel Sanctum for authentication in my Laravel 7/Vue SPA. Both have run into the same problem. Here are the methods:

https://blog.codecourse.com/setting-up-laravel-sanctum-airlock-for-spa-authentication-with-vue/

https://dev.to/aschmelyun/authenticating-a-vue-spa-is-easy-with-laravel-sanctum-392a

Both do much the same thing - install Sanctum, install the standard auth scaffolding, set up the middleware, add a dummy user or two. Then, use Axios to hit the `sanctum/csrf-cookie` route, then the `/login` routes, passing in an email and password.

However, with both methods, I get the same issue - a 401 'Unauthenticated' error. The Network tab of the browser dev tools shows that the `sanctum/csrf-cookie route` returns 204 and the Laravel session and XSRF cookies are set. The `login` route shows 302 and a redirect to /home which is the standard Laravel auth redirect. Then when it hits the route defined in the api.php file:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

It returns 401 - Unauthenticated.

Now, the only thing that makes this work seemingly as intended is tweaking the mapApiRoutes() function in RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```

Changing the middleware property from 'api' to 'web' fixes the issue. But that seems to be a complete bodge and something that I shouldn't need to do.

I have followed both methods to the letter - all the domains, middleware etc are set up exactly the same in both cases.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you set the session domain in .env? I skimmed through both links but don't think I caught anything about session domains. Also, documentation is a 100 times better than those links.

Comment: @user3532758 what do you mean? the SESSION_DOMAIN variable or SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS?

Comment: both needs to be set. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#cors-and-cookies `domain` here refers to `SESSION_DOMAIN`

Comment: According to the docs, SESSION_DOMAIN only needs to be set if you're using a subdomain. Also, neither of the two methods I followed make any mention of it, from fresh installs.

Comment: Try setting it, worth a shot, no?

Comment: What would I set it to if I'm just using the built in Artisan server, localhost:8000?

Comment: I would assume ".localhost"

Comment: Tried it, no dice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220439/discussion-between-user3532758-and-elendilthetall).

Comment: try set SESSION_DOMAIN=false and clear cache

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem but when I replaced
`->middleware('api')` with `->middleware('web')`
it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel `api` guard works based on a token, not on the session. It looks like you have three guards in place: `web`, `api` and `sanctum`. Could it be that you're logging in on `web` or `api`, while still requiring authentication through the `sanctum` guard as well?

Comment: As far as I know all you need to authenticate with Sanctum is hit the sanctum/csrf-cookie route. In any case, I am doing exactly what the two sources I linked to, and the Laravel docs, say to do. Hit the cookie route, hit the login route. It's all just the default, out of the box automagic Laravel stuff, I haven't changed a thing other than what it tells me to.